# state object with Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm using the Rx framework to perform async requests, this is all working OK, however I need to be able to pass a state object between the request / response as once I process the response, I need to know some additional information that was only known when the request was made, hence I want to pass in a state object somehow.

Currently I am using a method as:

```
 public void ProcessGetRequest(WebRequest request, Action<WebResponse> handle, Action<Exception> error, int delaySeconds = 0)
        {
            request.Method = "GET";

            Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse)().Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, delaySeconds)).ObserveOnDispatcher().SubscribeOnDispatcher().Subscribe(handle, error);
        }
```

On the request.BeginGetResponse method, I know you can pass a state object, and access that state object via the IAsyncResult object returned, but cant find a way to do it within the Rx / Observable framework as above. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be quite simple. Pass the state via a closure.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats what I ended up doing (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing is as below:

```
  public void ProcessGetRequest<T>(WebRequest request, Action<WebResponse,T> handle, Action<Exception,T> error, T state, int delaySeconds = 0)
        {
            request.Method = "GET";

            Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse)().Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, delaySeconds)).ObserveOnDispatcher().SubscribeOnDispatcher().Subscribe(x=>handle(x,state),y=>error(y,state));
        }
```

Comment: You can now make the state strongly-typed. There's no need longer any need to make them `object`.